# How can I know how the file copied to my Output?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have 6 projects in my Solution. So when I rebuild my solution one dll file with the same name will copy inside all my project. My question is how i can know which reference or with file is copying this dll file.

Comment: Check each project's references.

Comment: References have properties. one property is called "Copy local". according to your description, it's set to `true` for that reference in all 6 projects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't have a reference with that copied file name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSBuild verbosity settings in Visual Studio Options. It's in Tools->Options menu of VS. Then select **Project And Solutions** and **Build And Run** in left listbox.

On that tab there are two MSBuild verbosity settings dropdownlist. You can set these to **Detailed** and inspect its outputs.